# to load view from second view to back view

Tags: iphone, zend-framework

i have application in which i have display question on allcard view and all answer are displayed on backside of view.i done this by addsubview:ansview in allcardmethod.
now i have onr button that will on ansview function of that button is that to go to allcard to dispaly new question but i can not achived this....
please help

Comment: Post your questions more clearly and try to accept the answers then more people will help you..

Comment: If you are using "addSubView", use "removeFromSuperView" as suggested by "Sat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use navigation Controller than use

[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

where viewController is object of your controller class

and also you can use

[self.navigationController popToViewController:YES];

if u can add view using addSubView method than 
use removeFromSuperView method

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly,you want to remove your second view from super view.try this code

```
 [ansview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

also try this

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```